# How to sort words by their relevance to a keyword?

Tags: arrays, json, sorting, elasticsearch

I'm currently working on a search using elasticsearch. We have a very large amount of users.

Here is the elasticsearch mapping:

```
PUT /example_index/_mapping/users
{
  "properties": {
    "user_autocomplete": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "completion": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "user_autocomplete_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "standard"
        }
      }
    },
    "firstName": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "text"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the search query.
For example, I get 3 records

```
GET example_index/users/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 3,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "*ro*",
      "fields": [
        "firstName",
        "lastName"
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "user_suggestions": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 3,
        "field": "user_autocomplete.raw"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the output of elasticsearch

```
{
  "took": 53,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 13,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "example_index",
        "_type": "users",
        "_id": "08",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "firstName": "Eero",
          "lastName": "Saarinen",
          "user_autocomplete": "Eero Saarinen"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "example_index",
        "_type": "users",
        "_id": "16",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "firstName": "Aaron",
          "lastName": "Judge",
          "user_autocomplete": "Aaron Judge"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "example_index",
        "_type": "users",
        "_id": "20",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "firstName": "Robert",
          "lastName": "Langdon",
          "user_autocomplete": "Robert Langdon"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "user_suggestions": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 10,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Eero Saarinen",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Aaron Judge",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "Robert Langdon",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I need result like in the following order:

1. Robert Langdon
2. Aaron Judge
3. Eero Saarinen

I have tried order method. It won't work. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What kind of ordering will that be?

Comment: @Zico Search term is 'ro', so Robert Langdon comes first. and so.

Comment: Without defining an explicit order, document order is returned based on score.  You can see that all documents have the same score, because they all match on only one field.  Query string does not score a document based on location of match within a field.  What is the specific ordering you are looking for?

Comment: Yes. I need order based on the score.  How to calculate the score.?
If search term is `"query": "*ro*"` score is equal to 1. if  search term is `"query": "ro"` score is calculatiing .